# Viewing full version tree in git

Tags: git, gitk

I am using the command line version of Git and gitk. I want to see the full version tree, not just the part that is reachable from the currently checked out version. Is it possible?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
gitk --all
```

You can tell `gitk` what to display using anything that [`git rev-list` understands](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html), so if you just want a few branches, you can do:

```
gitk master origin/master origin/experiment
```

... or more exotic things like:

```
gitk --simplify-by-decoration --all
```

Answer (score 357):

if you happen to not have a graphical interface available you can also print out the commit graph on the command line:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

if this command complains with an invalid option --oneline, use:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Comment: who needs gitk when we have gitl!  alias gitl='git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all'

Comment: `alias gl='git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all'`. Why type more than needed ;)

Comment: I have hope command line abbreviations were invented before tab completion.  They only benefit those who use those commands a lot and those with crazy memories.

Answer (score 149):

1. When I'm in my work place with terminal only, I use:

   `git log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate`

   [image]
2. When the OS support GUI, I use:

   `gitk --all`

   [image]
3. When I'm in my home Windows PC, I use my own [GitVersionTree](https://github.com/crc8/GitVersionTree)

   [image]

Comment: Perfect answer for me. My OS supports GUI so second option is my way to go but let`s say I just wanna peek the graph from command line very quickly : is there some way to avoid typing all of those switches from the first version, or you just re-type them all the time ? Thank you.

Comment: @rchrd I would set them as alias by running `git config --global alias.ver "log --oneline --graph --color --all --decorate"` and only need to type `git ver` thereafter.

Answer (score 28):

There is a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/1515058) to the same question.
Adding following lines to "~/.gitconfig":

```
[alias]
lg1 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --date=relative --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all
lg2 = log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all
lg = !"git lg1"
```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't need branch or tag name:
`git log --oneline --graph --all --no-decorate`

If you don't even need color (to avoid tty color sequence):
`git log --oneline --graph --all --no-decorate --no-color`

And a handy alias (in .gitconfig) to make life easier:

```
[alias]
  tree = log --oneline --graph --all --no-decorate
```

Only last option takes effect, so it's even possible to override your alias:

```
git tree --decorate
```

Answer (score -1):

```bash
function gtree() {
  if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]] && which gitk; then
     gitk --all
  else
     git log --graph --pretty=online --abbrev-commit --all --decorate
  fi
}
```