# What is the parallel of clearvtree in git?

Tags: git, clearcase

I have used clearcase. We have clearvtree command to show the version tree of a particular file. Is there a command in git to show the version tree of a file, visually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call **[`gitk`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk)** on a singular file:

```
gitk -- aFile
```

As mentioned in "[Viewing full version tree in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5361023/6309)":

> You can tell `gitk` what to display using anything that [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) understands,

Note that you can get a similar result, directly in command-line: see "[Unable to show a Git tree in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064431/6309)".